Pythonic parallelized streaming of batches (list-of-dicts) of JSON into a single file write
I have a multiprocessing thread pool where each job returns a requested batch of JSON (an array of objects). I want all results to write into a single file, but without storing the full result (as a single list) in-memory due to RAM constraints (the full result contains about 1.5 million records totaling about 1.5 GB).
I see solutions that suggest the use of json-stream but these do not seem to account for batching (they handle either a list or dicts, not a list of lists of dicts). I also see solutions suggesting string manipulations, e.g., opening the file and writing a [ followed by a batch of objects, separated by writes of , , followed by a trimming of trailing , and ] characters...
Is there a way to do this, either using an imported library or in a "safer" manner?
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def thread(worker, jobs, threads):

    pool = ThreadPool(threads)

    with open("tmp.json", "w") as f:

        for result in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(worker, jobs), total=len(jobs)):

            # 1. stream each object from each result array)
            for element in result:

                ### CODE GOES HERE ###



            # 2. just stream the result array
            
            ### CODE GOES HERE ###





Use logging library. It works perfectly in different streams and correctly locks file while appending the data. You can configure logging formatting in such a way that only your text will be appended in the file.

@JohnnyCheesecutter can you elaborate on this?
